# ¿Hay alguna forma de privatizar el contenido de un iframe?

Tags: php, html, aplicación-web, iframe, arcgis

Estoy trabajando con **ArcGIS**, creando un visor de mapas. Al parecer puedes incluir ese visor en tu pag. web, que es lo que quiero (una aplicación web). El problema con el que me estoy encontrando es que el método para insertarlo en mi documento html es mediante un `<iframe>`. El src contiene una dirección url que, quien sepa utilizar el inspeccionador del navegador, podrá obtener fácilmente y así no tendría necesidad de utilizar mi aplicación. Tendría esa url y podría acceder directamente copiando y pegándola en el buscador. (Adjunto código):

```
 <iframe id="visor" src="http://estoEsLaURLdelVisor"></iframe>
```

**Me gustaría que no pudieran obtener dicha url, no sé si hay alguna forma de privatizar el contenido del iframe**, o, si alguien sabe de **ArcGIS**, que pudiera darme alguna solución para que ese visor que genero, **no sea "tan abierto al público"**.

Muchas gracias.

(Añado la etiqueta PHP, pues estoy trabajando con un control de usuarios con dicho lenguaje)

Comment: La URL... ¿es una URL a tu servidor o a ArcGIS? No está claro si hablas de proteger "tu visor" o de evitar que la gente acceda independientemente **al visor de ArcGIS**.

Comment: Buenas @SJuan76 me refiero a evitar que la gente acceda independientemente al visor de ArcGIS. Un ejemplo de iframe seria asi: <iframe width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
src="http://arcgis.com/apps/View/index.html?appid=6b6a075eca8d4899958fb273710a6806"></iframe>

Comment: viendo la documentación, pareciera que necesitas montar tu propio servidor ArcGis y ahí podes limitar el acceso sólo a través de tu dominio

Answer (score -1):

1.- En javascript, en la página principal, colocar la siguiente función:

function SetSrc(x)
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById('visor');
    iframe.src = x;
}

2.- Y en la parte html:

<iframe id = "visor" src="x.html"></iframe>

3.- Luego, en otro archivo llamado x.html colocar en el head:

<script type="text/javascript">
        parent.SetSrc("http://www.arcgis.....");
</script>

4.- Ofuscar el código de la página x.html con un ofuscador de códigos, no se si está permitido publicar nombres pero se de uno bueno.

---

Al cargarse x.html llama a la función SetSrc de la página principal dando un parámetro que es el URL para cambiar el contenido del iframe pero sin cambiar el código fuente de la página principal y como el código de x.html estaría ofuscado sería muy dificultoso ver el parámetro URL.